# calling class and function name from database in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I have some 20 class with functions in python:

```
class class_1:
    def display():
        return('This is 1st Class')

class class_2:
    def display():
        return('This is 2nd Class and some more lines')

#Like this 20 class I have
```

Now when to call which class, its stored in database:

| tag | class | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab | 2 | 0 |
| cd | 3 | 1 |
| ef | 1 | 0 |
| gh | 1 | 1 |

Now I when I run the below code:

```
data = db_fetchquery("SELECT class FROM table WHERE status = '0'")

for row in data:
    display = class_{row[0]}.display()
    print(display)
```

The result I am expecting is:

***This is 2nd Class and some more lines***

***This is 1st Class***

But I am getting ***SyntaxError: invalid syntax***

I also tried dictionary:

```
data = db_fetchquery("SELECT class FROM table WHERE status = '0'")

for row in data:
   id = {'x' : 'class_'+row[0]}
   display = id['x'].display()
```

This gave me ***AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'display'***

Comment: why do you need to define class per display function?

Comment: Why do you need multiple display functions instead of a single parameterized function?

Comment: both ~ question is having just an example but in real code is different for each function in each class for example class_1 function will fetch A from B database and do some calculations and some other activities, class_2 function will fetch X from Y database and do some calculations and some other activities. Each class is having 4/5 functions

Answer (score 1):

The code below is the direction you need to take. The code takes input from the user (your code will replace it with DB call) and execute the proper function.

```
import inspect

import sys


def display_1():
    print('display_1')


def display_2():
    print('display_2')


funcs = {name: obj for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]) if inspect.isfunction(obj)}
func_id = input('Type func id:')
final_name = 'display_{}'.format(func_id)
func = funcs.get(final_name)
if not func:
    print('cant find the func ' + final_name)
else:
    func()
```